# How to manipulate nested attributes in JAXB

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling

Hello I'm using JAXB to save and load a project in my application. The thing is That I have a structure like this:

```
Class A{
   private ObservableList<ClassB> list;
   private String property;
}

ClassB{
  private String description;
  private ObservableList<ClassC> students;
}

ClassC{
  private String name,address;
  private Integer age;
}
```

And I really don't know how to make the `XMLAdapterClass` for the `ClassB` for example. JAXB for my project only takes `String`, `Integer`,`ObservableList<String>` but not the attributes of type defined by myself as `ClassA`,`ClassB` and `ClassC`
I was looking and reading some post in internet, but the examples are really very basic, and I need to know how to manipulate nested attributes of non primitive type.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little on your question? Are you a schema for your marshalling and unmarshalling? Do each of your classes represent an XML element? If so, which element should your attribute be attached to?

Comment: @kirstyannelouise hi, I made [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33851127/marshaling-classes-in-java-ignore-some-attributes) is the same thing, but more elaborated. I am asking again because I was thinking the last was a lot extensive. I dont have schemas, I only have 2 AdapterClass for attributes of type observableList and StrinProperty. I only need a guide, how to do it

Comment: I understand. Would you be able to post a sample of XML structure?

Comment: @kirstyannelouise do you mean a sample of XML structure that I want to generate?because the one that I'm generating is very simple and doesnt have a lot of the attributes